# OpenStack Mitaka - Instances have no net connectivity

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I've followed the Mitaka setup guide for my first OpenStack cloud.  This all went ok (2nd time around!), however i'm now having issues with networking.  The instance launches ok, and it's assigned an IP via DHCP, but it won't ping.  I don't know if my network is setup right, so i've provided the appropriate outputs below.

I setup Mitaka with option 2 - 'self service networks', but for simplicity i've only created a Flat DHCP 'provider' network just to get a feel for things.  On my test setup I only have 1 working public IP address, x.x.x.111

```
    root@controller:~# openstack network list
+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name     | Subnets                              |
+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| 2a14a7d2-929b-49f8-8711-f5f1742fc523 | provider | 17681cf7-5ac7-426d-8ea8-91b3cf810141 |
+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+


root@controller:~# openstack network show  2a14a7d2-929b-49f8-8711-f5f1742fc523
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | UP                                   |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                      |
| availability_zones        | nova                                 |
| created_at                | 2016-04-29T19:25:56                  |
| description               |                                      |
| id                        | 2a14a7d2-929b-49f8-8711-f5f1742fc523 |
| ipv4_address_scope        | None                                 |
| ipv6_address_scope        | None                                 |
| mtu                       | 1500                                 |
| name                      | provider                             |
| port_security_enabled     | True                                 |
| project_id                | 4864e2e05328471a849c9cb26ed4e27e     |
| provider:network_type     | flat                                 |
| provider:physical_network | provider                             |
| provider:segmentation_id  | None                                 |
| router_external           | Internal                             |
| shared                    | True                                 |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   | 17681cf7-5ac7-426d-8ea8-91b3cf810141 |
| tags                      | []                                   |
| updated_at                | 2016-05-02T20:35:32                  |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+


root@controller:~# openstack subnet show 17681cf7-5ac7-426d-8ea8-91b3cf810141
+-------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field             | Value                                |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------+
| allocation_pools  | x.x.164.111-x.x.164.111      |
| cidr              | x.x.164.0/24                     |
| created_at        | 2016-04-30T07:16:23                  |
| description       |                                      |
| dns_nameservers   | 213.186.33.99                        |
| enable_dhcp       | True                                 |
| gateway_ip        | x.x.164.252                      |
| host_routes       |                                      |
| id                | 17681cf7-5ac7-426d-8ea8-91b3cf810141 |
| ip_version        | 4                                    |
| ipv6_address_mode | None                                 |
| ipv6_ra_mode      | None                                 |
| name              | provider                             |
| network_id        | 2a14a7d2-929b-49f8-8711-f5f1742fc523 |
| project_id        | 4864e2e05328471a849c9cb26ed4e27e     |
| subnetpool_id     | None                                 |
| updated_at        | 2016-04-30T07:16:23                  |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------+

root@controller:~# openstack server show f604d990-cadc-433c-b617-e3ea5f68f3ad
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                                | Value                                                    |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                    | AUTO                                                     |
| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone          | nova                                                     |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                 | compute1                                                 |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname  | compute1                                                 |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name        | instance-0000000c                                        |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state               | 1                                                        |
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state                | None                                                     |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                  | active                                                   |
| OS-SRV-USG:launched_at               | 2016-05-03T15:30:34.000000                               |
| OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at             | None                                                     |
| accessIPv4                           |                                                          |
| accessIPv6                           |                                                          |
| addresses                            | provider=x.x.x.111                                       |
| config_drive                         |                                                          |
| created                              | 2016-05-03T15:30:27Z                                     |
| flavor                               | m1.medium (3)                                            |
| hostId                               | a8af2b53ead6cfc050a24e875e3c42fa32ece6c3002652123cd04d2c |
| id                                   | f604d990-cadc-433c-b617-e3ea5f68f3ad                     |
| image                                | Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (63576a8c-408f-4a59-947d-d7ab3bd60a67)  |
| key_name                             | mykey                                                    |
| name                                 | test                                                     |
| os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached | []                                                       |
| progress                             | 0                                                        |
| project_id                           | 4864e2e05328471a849c9cb26ed4e27e                         |
| properties                           |                                                          |
| security_groups                      | [{u'name': u'default'}]                                  |
| status                               | ACTIVE                                                   |
| updated                              | 2016-05-03T15:30:34Z                                     |
| user_id                              | 93f3b9fa687647e2838afac8f40ae020                         |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

root@controller:~# openstack security group show default
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Value                                                                                                  |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| description | Default security group                                                                                 |
| id          | 2884d4ac-a91f-411a-9a2b-eb249ddf5ef0                                                                   |
| name        | default                                                                                                |
| project_id  | 4864e2e05328471a849c9cb26ed4e27e                                                                       |
| rules       | id='10f8ef55-2275-4f25-94f9-4e38dbec3ccf', ip_protocol='tcp', ip_range='0.0.0.0/0', port_range='22:22' |
|             | id='b5ce2770-f099-4944-b7f8-8cc660c09a40', remote_security_group='default'                             |
|             | id='eda22bb6-529b-45f7-b4ab-48ef1b8b271a', ip_protocol='icmp', ip_range='0.0.0.0/0'                    |
|             | id='ef5edd41-c81c-42dc-8f95-26ad9ff20dc4', remote_security_group='default'                             |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: the default security groups allows all egress traffic - so unless you have changed that you can rule that out, you should be able to get internet access on all private and public IP's - for diagnostics like pinging you need to send commands to the same network name space as your virtual routers/networks - what is the output of ip netns - have a look here for more steps https://www.rdoproject.org/troubleshooting/networking/

Comment: ip netns outputs nothing, on the controller and compute node.

Comment: can you list your bridge interfaces and network agents 'neutron agent-list' & 'brctl show' and 'route n' unfortunately there are lots of reasons to have connectivity problems in openstack - are you deploying it manually?